# Basic Stack in C++ Using Array

Tags: c++, stack

I  wrote a stack class in C++ using arrays of fixed width. Could anyone review my code ? I didn't comment on any of the functions, because I thought class itself is self explanatory. Is it a wrong approach or which kind of comments can I write?

````
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class Stack {
  public:
    Stack(void);    //ctor
    void push(const T& item);
    T pop(void);
    void clear(void);
    T top(void) const;
    bool empty(void) const;
    bool full(void) const;
    void print(void) const;
  private:
    static const int MAX = 50;
    T list[MAX];
    int topPtr;
};

template <class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(void) {
    this->topPtr = -1;
}

template <class T>
void Stack<T>::push(const T& item) {

    if(this->topPtr == this->MAX - 1) {
        std::cerr << "Stack overflow. Can't push" << '\n';
    } else {
        this->topPtr += 1;
        this->list[topPtr] = item;
    }
}

template <class T>
T Stack<T>::pop(void) {
    if(this->topPtr < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Stack is empty. Can't pop" << '\n';
    } else {
        T r_value = this->list[this->topPtr];
        this->topPtr -= 1;
        return r_value;
    }
}

template <class T>
void Stack<T>::clear(void) {
    this->topPtr = -1;
}

template <class T>
T Stack<T>::top(void)const {
    if(this->topPtr < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Stack is empty. No top element." << '\n';
    } else {
        return this->list[topPtr];
    }
}

template <class T>
bool Stack<T>::empty(void) const {
    return (this->topPtr == -1);
}

template <class T>
bool Stack<T>::full(void) const {
    return (this->topPtr == this->MAX -1);
}

template <class T>
void Stack<T>::print(void) const {
    for (int i = this->topPtr; i >= 0; i--)
        std::cout << this->list[i] << '\n';
}

```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a nice implementation! Here are my thoughts,

- `this` is implicit. Consider removing `this`, i.e. use `topPtr` instead of `this->topPtr`. Similarly, `void` doesn't need to be used as an argument, consider removing `void`, i.e. `top()` instead of `top(void)`.
- Consider using `std::size_t` for `MAX`. Also, consider naming `MAX` as `MAX_SIZE` since it is slightly more descriptive. If using `std::size_t`, make sure not to subtract one from `MAX` to avoid overflow. Instead, when checking for equality, add one to the other side.
- It might be nicer to use a `T*` instead of an `int` for `topPtr`. `nullptr` could be used instead of `-1` initially for `topPtr`.
- For `print` consider passing a `std::ostream` object. This allows for decoupling and one could pass in a `std::ostringstream` instead of `std::cout` if desired.
- For `top` and `pop`, consider using `assert` instead `if/else`. An exception could also be used, but I think `assert` is a little nicer. To include a message, use something similar `assert(!empty() && "Stack is empty. Can't pop");`. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert. Maybe add a comment about the requirements of these functions.
- Consider adding documentation for any public function. Include information such as what the function returns, requires, and modifies. For example, `top` requires there are element in the stack.

Comment: All good comments, the issue with `assert()` it won't do anything when compiled in what you would call "Release" mode.

Comment: Thank you @Milo Hartsoe for the comments. I removed `this`, changed `int MAX` to  `std::size_t MAX_SIZE`, changed `int topPtr` to `T* topPtr` and introduced new variable `std::size_t size` to keep stack size, passed `std::ostream`object to `print` function. I guess all lead to a better structure.

Answer (score 2):

- `#include <stdlib.h>` is unnecessary.
- C++ is not Java. All those `this->` could be safely dropped.
- `pop` does not return anything if the stack is empty. This invokes an undefined behavior.
- Do not print from such low level utility methods. Printing tells nothing to the caller. Use success/failure return value.
- C++ containers are expected (in fact, required, see 23.2.1 for details) to destroy elements in as they are removed.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I changed the return type of `pop` to `void`, and removed `this` pointers. I want to ask can the content of a static array be removed? I made a search, but it looks like not possible.